# How to properly use nested include query with sequelize in nodes(mysql)

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

How to properly use nested include query with sequelize(nodejs)

my nested include query with sequelize is giving me this error

```
"category is associated to course using an alias. You've included an alias (Category), but it does not match the alias defined in your association."
```

what i want is from the users list, i want to get all the tcourses, then from that, i will get all the courses then from that i want to get the list of all the categories

I don't know what I did that is wrong, I just need it to work, am still new to nodejs

here is the code

```
export default {
  Query: {
    users: combineResolvers(isAdmin, async (parent, args, { models }) => {
      return await models.User.findAll();
    }),
  },  
  User: { 
    messages: async (user, args, { models }) => {
      return await models.Message.findAll({
        where: { userId: user.id }, 
      });
    },     
    tcourses: async (user, args, { models }) => {
      return await models.TCourses.findAll({
        where: { UserId: user.id },
        include: [{model: models.Course, as: 'Course', include: [{model: models.Category, as: 'Category'}]}]
      })
    }
  },
}
```

here is my tcourses model code

```
const tcourses = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const TCourses = sequelize.define('tcourses', {
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            autoIncrement: true,
            unique: true,
            primaryKey: true,
            field: 'id'
        },
    }, {
        timestamps: false
    });

    TCourses.associate = models => {
        TCourses.belongsTo(models.Course,{ as: 'Course', required: false})
        TCourses.belongsTo(models.User,{ as: 'User'})
    };
    return TCourses;
};
export default tcourses;
```

here is my Course model code

```
const course = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const Course = sequelize.define('course', {
        Title: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            validate: {
                notEmpty: {
                    args: true,
                    msg: 'Enter Course Title'
                }
            }, 
        },
    }, {
        timestamps: false
    })
    Course.associate = models => {
        Course.belongsTo(models.Category, { as: 'Cat'})
        Course.hasMany(models.Requirements,{onDelete: 'CASCADE', foreignKey: 'CourseId'})
        Course.belongsTo(models.User, { as: 'Owners'})
        Course.hasMany(models.Audience,{onDelete: 'CASCADE', foreignKey: 'CourseId'})
        Course.hasMany(models.TCourses,{onDelete: 'CASCADE', foreignKey: 'CourseId'})
    };
    return Course
  }; 
  export default course
```

here is my Category model code

```
const category = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const Category = sequelize.define('category', {
            catName: {
                type: DataTypes.STRING,
                validate: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        args: true,
                        msg: 'Enter Category name'
                    }
                },
            },
    }, {
            timestamps: false
    });

    Category.associate = models => {
        Category.hasMany(models.Course,{onDelete: 'CASCADE',  foreignKey: 'CatId'})
        Category.hasMany(models.TCategory,{onDelete: 'CASCADE', foreignKey: 'CategoryId'})
    };
    return Category;
};

  export default category;
```

pls how can i make it to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to provide the same alias for model in both include statement and while defining association.

The error also specifies the same,

```
"category is associated to course using an alias. You've included an alias (Category), but it does not match the alias defined in your association."
```

While querying the DB you have specified the alias for category table as **Category**

```
models.TCourses.findAll({
    where: { UserId: user.id },
    include: [{model: models.Course, as: 'Course', include: [{model: models.Category, as: 'Category'}]}]
  })
```

In the Course model you have defined the association as **Cat**

```
Course.belongsTo(models.Category, { as: 'Cat'})
```

Now you have to make it same, i,e use either **Cat** or **Catgory** at both the places.